# (Java) - how to display the output we set

Tags: java

This is the java code, how can i display like example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;


   for (i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++)
   {
       for (j = 1; j<= 5; j++)
       {
        if (i % 2 == 0 )
        {
            System.out.println ( j + "/5 = " + i /10.0);
            //the output should be 
            // 1/5 = 0.2
            // 2/5 = 0.4
            // 3/5 = 0.6
            // 4/5 = 0.8
            // 5/5 = 1.0

        }
       }

   }

    System.out.println("--------------------");
   }

 }
```

How i can display the output like 1/5 = 0.2  2/5 = 0.4  3/5 = 0.6  4/5 = 0.8  5/5 = 1.0

Comment: cast it to double: `(double)(i /10.0)`

Comment: this the output when I follow the code I post :http://i.gyazo.com/08569a4ba364aaa20a16af00d613a1f3.png

Comment: Why do you need 2 for loop? System.out.println ( j + "/5 = " + (j/5.0)); only inner loop is required

Comment: the output different http://i.gyazo.com/941df5abba528adf445ea26eb143941b.png

Comment: you should remove the if () too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing way too much here. Simply do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i = 1; i<= 5; i++)
     {
         System.out.println ( i + "/5 = " + i / 5.0);
     }
     System.out.println("--------------------");
}
```

Output:

```
1/5 = 0.2
2/5 = 0.4
3/5 = 0.6
4/5 = 0.8
5/5 = 1.0
--------------------
```

Comment: 1/5 = 0.2
2/5 = 0.4
3/5 = 0.6
4/5 = 0.8
5/5 = 1.0

Comment: the answer must like this

Comment: @ikramlim just google java tutorials they should have lots of examples and code you can try out...

Comment: Why the downvote please atleast say why you downvoted the correct answer?

Comment: i have no click downvote. I still can't to click vote button. I have 10 reputations only..

Comment: I can't click downvote or even vote: http://i.gyazo.com/7e3ab03697bec26b138815ddf46537c9.png

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;


       for (i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++)
       {  

                System.out.println ( i + "/5 = " + (i/5.0));           

       }

        System.out.println("--------------------");
       }
```

Comment: output is:-1/5 = 0.2
2/5 = 0.4
3/5 = 0.6
4/5 = 0.8
5/5 = 1.0
6/5 = 1.2
7/5 = 1.4
8/5 = 1.6
9/5 = 1.8
10/5 = 2.0
--------------------